# Shared preferences true by default for some reason

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want my button to show "catch" at the very beginning if there is no key the same as the name of a current pokemon and "release" if there is one and its value is true. I send "false" by default with getBoolean. But for some reason, the first text I see with every new pokemon is "release". What could be wrong?

Edit: I include the entire onCreate method and the button's onClick method along with the layout.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Catch"
    android:onClick="toggleCatch"
    android:visibility="visible" />

SharedPreferences catchStorage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_name);
    numberTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_number);
    type1TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type1);
    type2TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type2);
    pokemonName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    catchStorage = getSharedPreferences("catchStorage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Button catchBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    if(catchStorage.getBoolean(pokemonName, false)){
        catchBut.setText("Release");
    }
    else {
        catchBut.setText("Catch");
    }

    load();
}

public void toggleCatch(View view) {
    Button catched = (Button)view;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = catchStorage.edit();
    if(catchStorage.getBoolean(pokemonName, false)){
        editor.putBoolean(pokemonName, false);
        editor.commit();
        catched.setText("Catch");
    }
    else {
        editor.putBoolean(pokemonName, true);
        editor.commit();
        catched.setText("Release");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you uninstall the app to make sure the sharedPreference is empty first?

Comment: I tried it and found another problem. When everything is clean and I haven't clicked on any button yet, it shows what I want. But when I click on one button, every pokemon's buttons now show "release" even though I haven't changed them or used "putBoolean" for them.

Comment: That sounds like a new question to me. It relates to how you start the single activity and how the list is made

Answer (score 0):

The value of shared preference will be set **default value** by the system (false in this case) if the variable was never accessed by the user or was never created, if you or the user changed this value, the default value is ignored.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

So either the value is accessed before or it is set some value.

More complete code snippet may help to find the reason.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the logic of default values, but still don't see what's wrong. Looks like I did everything correct. But this is a machine, right? It just executes commands. Therefore there must be some mistake.